# sql GROUP HAVING selection

Tags: sql, group-by, having

I want to project the **pid** indexes for all products which have the same title, as I'm using the following as a sub query.

Product(**pid**, title)

```
SELECT p.title
FROM product p
group by title
HAVING ( COUNT(p.title) > 1 )
```

this outputs the duplicate titles fine, but how do I project the **pid**'s instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT p.pid, p.title
FROM product p 
     INNER JOIN 
     (SELECT p.title
      FROM product p
      GROUP BY title
      HAVING (COUNT(p.title) > 1)) t ON t.title = p.title
```

here is an example of it working with sqlfiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/25e77/1

Comment: sorry, this returns 38000 records, there are only 51 duplicate titles in the db.

Comment: @AlasdairC how many titles does your sup query return? also, did you change anything in my query?

Comment: thought I didn't, but on second look, it totally does return the correct number of results, the pid of every title which appears more than once, which is exactly what I need, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think a self-join is the easiest answer on this case. Notice how we're testing for different PIDs but same titles:

```
SELECT p1.pid FROM products p1 JOIN products p2 
              ON p1.pid <> p2.pid AND p1.title = p2.title;
```

(I tested it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c8b8d/18)

Comment: if I put in a `distinct` before p1.pid it returns the same number as @Bassam-mehanni 's answer